# How to lazy init a Map in lambda functions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to run a lambda function and collect a map of exceptions that occurred during the transformation.

Problem: I'd prefer not having to instantiate my `Map` before, because most computation runs will complete just without any error.

Thus, I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
Map<Integer, Throwable> errors;

Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream().map(number -> {
    try {
        return heavyComputation(number);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (errors == null) errors = new LinkedHashMap<>(); //TODO
        errors.put(number, ex);
        return null;
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Question: how can I lazy initialize my error Map?

Comment: I don't see the problem with initializing a `Map` for it to end up not being used.

Comment: @rkosegi  `.orElse` does not take a method reference.  Just use `new LinkedHashMap<>()`.

Comment: what is the return type/signature of `heavyComputation` just to know the code in question better in terms of current design?

Comment: @membersound what approach did you end up taking? I'm looking for ideas as I'm facing the same question.

Comment: @armandino I did not find a solution to lazy-init an error-collector. Thus I have initialize the error `Map` just before the iteration..

Comment: No worries @membersound, thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

Change your approach a little. In your `stream().map()`, return a value-or-error container, rather than just the values. Look at `CompletableFuture`, for example.

Comment: Ok, but if I'd have to create a container class for my return values, then I'd rather initialize a `Map` that is mostly not used, instead of generating containers who usually only contain one object.

Comment: I was assuming that you were using the concrete classes in this example as stand-ins for classes which would actually be heavyweight to initialize. You have to remember that in your example, the map will be allocated on the stack, which is super lightweight. I would recommend that you would actually check what kind of memory pressure and allocation overhead your use case actually produces, if you haven't yet.

Comment: Ok so this might be a case of over-optimization in case of `Map`. Still, I thought there would be a solution for cases with heavy-init fields that should be lazy.